# Is it possible to host the clientaccesspolicy.xml file with the ASP.NET Development Server?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, cross-domain, vs-devserver

I have a solution with two service projects (one is hosting a unit test silverlight application and other is providing the services being tested).  Because of cross-domain policy, I have to publish the primary service site to IIS before the unit test site can consume a service.

Is it possible to host the clientaccesspolicy.xml file on ASP.NET Development Server so I can run these without needing to do an IIS publish first?  OR, does Visual Studio provide a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a "more elegant" solution, however you can serve a clientaccesspolicy.xml file from a ASP.NET development server, its after all just a static file.  Just add it to the web project as a Content file.

Comment: Well, feel a little silly now.  It was as simple as that.  Thanks!